# How can I input touch events to Android remotely without a cable?

Tags: android, remote-control

I am trying to generate touch events on an Android phone and stream the screen to a web application. I want to do this remotely without a USB cable and not require that the phone be rooted.

**What I tried**: **ADB** over USB allows me to generate touch events, and ADB over network does the same but both of these require first connecting with cable and then configuring the Android device. I am not able to do this without a cable. I also explored making an **Accessibility Service**. It allows you to monitor touch events and input some things like text and clicking on buttons but doesn't allow arbitrary touch events. I can also use **MonkeyRunner** but that requires a cable too.

**Others like this**: Apps like [Vysor](http://www.vysor.io/) and Android Screen Monitor allow me to input touch events and stream the screen but both require a USB cable. I would like to do this without any cable. [Mobizen](https://www.mobizen.com/?locale=en) achieves this without a cable but I have no idea how they do it.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adb over wifi?

Comment: i also want to monitor touch events remotely on different device. Can you please let me know that it can be accessible with Accessibility Service ?